# How to compare int variables in switch-statements in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

In if statements you can just use modulus to check if something is divisible for example 'if (number  % 3 == 0);'.

When trying to do the same in switch statements as 'case (number  % 3 == 0):' it says required: int, provided: boolean. How do I solve this? Also a short explanation of why you would do it as you say would be very appreciated!

Doing a basic practice to see if the number entered is divisible with 3, 5, both or neither. Doing the if statement was easy but this one not as.

Currently code is (the same it was in if form cause I couldnt figure out what to do). Problem bolded:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numberEntered = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = numberEntered.nextInt();


    switch (number) {

        case **(number  % 3 == 0)**:
            System.out.println("Fizz");
            break;
```

Tried to parse into boolean and some weird random things but nothing I tried to come up with worked for me.

Comment: You can't do this with switch in Java (not yet anyway).

Comment: put the expression (number % 3) in the switch and a constant (e.g. 0) in the case statement like this: `switch (number % 3) { case (0): ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numberEntered = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = numberEntered.nextInt();

    switch (number  % 3) {

        case (0):
            System.out.println("Fizz");
            break;
```

Comment: Can you actually bundle both (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0) after switch ( so that it would understand all of the possible results? Which would be divisible by 3, 5, both or neither and that neither would return the number entered by user.

 Currently like:

switch (number % 3 && number % 5) {

            case (1):
                System.out.println("Fizz");
                break;

            case (2):
                System.out.println("Buzz");
                break;

            case (3):
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
                break;

Comment: Update: This way it doews understand divisible by 3 and 5 (how does it udnerstand to check if divisible by 5 in case (1) after (0)? O.o

But doesnt understand the FizzBuzz when divisible with both 3 and 5

EDIT: When not divisible by 3 or 5 it returns fizzbuzz and not the number like I tried. Now im confused how the code is interpret without any indications towards what it should do.

Comment: @Jonnu for that scenario going with if-else is the best option. Switch won't give you the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
    switch (number % 3) {

    case (0):
        System.out.println("Fizz");
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As *Mark Rotteveel* already commented, probably there is no way to do it via Switch in Java.
I would recommend you to use nested IF statements here. Just like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numberEntered = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = numberEntered.nextInt();

    if((number%3==0) && (number%5==0)) {
        System.out.println("entered number is divisible with both 3 and 5!")
    } 
    else if (number%3==0) {
        System.out.println("entered number is divisible with 3!")
    }
    else if (number%5==0) {
        System.out.println("entered number is divisible with 5!")
    }
    else if (!(number%3==0) && !(number%5==0)) {
        System.out.println("entered number is NOT divisible with 3 or 5!")
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple use like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner numberEntered = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int number = numberEntered.nextInt();

    switch (number % 3 ) {
        case (0):
            System.out.println("Do something");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the FizzBuzz exercise, I would recommend using the ternary operator.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            int n = input.nextInt();
            if (n <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            String v = n % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz"
                    : n % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz"
                            : n % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz"
                                    : "Not divisible by 3 or 5";
            System.out.println(v);

        }
```

It works as follows:

```
int ret = boolean expression ? a : b.
```

If the expression is true, return a, otherwise return b. a and b may also be ternary expressions so they can be chained.

In the above code.

- If it is divisible by 15, then FizzBuzz
- else if by 3, Fizz
- else if by 5, Buzz
- else  not divisible by either.

Comment: I tried this but cause I have it as ( Scanner = numberEntered and int number = numberEntered.nextln()), it doesnt let me continue with % in the same line or afterwards without defining it as something. But also says "% cannot be applied to java.lang.string, int".

If I dont define it it says "; expected" and if I do it says the exception above.

Comment: @Jonnu see my edited answer.  You need to assign the value from  the `Scanner` to `n`